# What is the default ColorFunction for 3D plots?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, color

This should be a really simple question, but it isn't in the documentation for some perverse reason. I like the default `ColorFunction` that *Mathematica* uses for `Plot3D` and the like. I'd like to use the same color scheme for other *Mathematica* plots that don't have it as the automatic default. However, after looking through all of the Color Gradients listed by `ColorData["Gradients"]` I can't find any that match the effect of just setting `ColorFunction->Automatic`.

My question: What does *Mathematica* call its default color palette, why isn't it listed in `ColorData`, and how can I access it to apply it to other plots?

Comment: I think the default color scheme comes from `PlotStyle -> White, Lighting -> Automatic`, without setting any `ColorFunction`.

Answer (score 13):

I think the default color scheme comes from `PlotStyle -> White, Lighting -> Automatic`, without setting any `ColorFunction`.

Please compare the results of these two commands:

```
Row[{
    Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, ImageSize -> 200],
    Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, ImageSize -> 200,
           PlotStyle -> White,
           Lighting -> Automatic]
   }]
```

[image: image comparison]

Also, the [documentation for `Lighting`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Lighting.html) states *"If a color function is given to a plot, then neutral lighting is used automatically"*. Please compare the results of the following commands:

```
Row[{
    Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, ImageSize -> 200,
           ColorFunction -> (White &)],
    Show[
         Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, ImageSize -> 200,
                ColorFunction -> (White &)],
         Lighting -> Automatic]
  }]
```

[image: image comparison 2]

Comment: I think this has changed in version 10. Your first example produces slightly [different results](http://i.imgur.com/EcsnY6O.png) on my computer. Also do you know the default color/lighting used for version 10 for multiple plots? For example in `Plot3D[{Sin[x + y^2], Cos[x + y^2]}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}]` there are two surfaces with two different colors (yellow and blue), how can I plot only the second one `Plot3D[Cos[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}]` with the same blue style?

Comment: @xslittlegrass Yes I think the default settings has been changed. You need to use `PlotStyle -> somecolor, Lighting -> "Neutral"` to mimic the default style. But I'm not sure which exact color it is..

Comment: @xslittlegrass I think you can get the colors by this way: `Plot3D[Evaluate@Range[10],{x,0,1},{y,0,1},PlotPoints->2,MaxRecursion->0]//Cases[#,Directive[___,c_RGBColor,___]:>c,∞]&`.

Comment: @xslittlegrass And the `Lighting` is not `"Neutral"`, it's ............ 
``Lighting->{{"Ambient",RGBColor[0.30100577,0.22414668499999998`,0.090484535]},{"Directional",RGBColor[0.2642166,0.18331229999999998`,0.04261530000000001],ImageScaled[{0,2,2}]},{"Directional",RGBColor[0.2642166,0.18331229999999998`,0.04261530000000001],ImageScaled[{2,2,2}]},{"Directional",RGBColor[0.2642166,0.18331229999999998`,0.04261530000000001],ImageScaled[{2,0,2}]}}``.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm still not able to make it work. See [here](http://i.imgur.com/uSlJ6Jd.png). By the way how can you get the default lighting information?

Comment: @xslittlegrass You need to use `PlotStyle -> Directive[Specularity[White, 3], color[[2]]]`. Regarding the `Lighting`, try removing the `:> c` in your `In[39]`.

Comment: That works. Thanks!

Comment: @xslittlegrass You're welcome!

Comment: Is there a way to have the same color in all view angles? I tried "Lighting->None" but it didn't work!

Comment: @H.R. Sorry I'm not quite sure I understand your question. Can you show me an example please?

Answer (score 11):

The [howto/ChangeTheLightingOfPlots](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/ChangeTheLightingOfPlots.html) section of the documentation centre specifies the default lighting settings:

```
Graphics3D[Sphere[], 
 Lighting -> {{"Ambient", 
    RGBColor[{0.312, 0.188, 0.4}]}, {"Directional", 
    RGBColor[{0.8, 0., 0.}], ImageScaled[{2, 0, 2}]}, {"Directional", 
    RGBColor[{0., 0.8, 0.}], ImageScaled[{2, 2, 2}]}, {"Directional", 
    RGBColor[{0., 0., 0.8}], ImageScaled[{0, 2, 2}]}}]
```

So, the object coloring derives from using colored lights, not from a coloring function.

Comment: Aha I know I saw it somewhere! (+1)

Comment: Is there a way to have the same color in all view angles? I tried "Lighting->None" but it didn't work!

Answer (score 1):

Using `Trace` I extracted the default `PlotStyle` for many of the 3D plots:

```
Directive[Specularity[GrayLevel[1], 3], RGBColor[0.880722, 0.611041, 0.142051],   Lighting -> {{"Ambient", RGBColor[      0.30100577, 0.22414668499999998`, 0.090484535]}, {"Directional",      RGBColor[0.2642166, 0.18331229999999998`, 0.04261530000000001],      ImageScaled[{0, 2, 2}]}, {"Directional", RGBColor[      0.2642166, 0.18331229999999998`, 0.04261530000000001],      ImageScaled[{2, 2, 2}]}, {"Directional", RGBColor[      0.2642166, 0.18331229999999998`, 0.04261530000000001],      ImageScaled[{2, 0, 2}]}}, AbsoluteThickness[2]],  
Directive[Specularity[GrayLevel[1], 3], RGBColor[   0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798],   Lighting -> {{"Ambient", RGBColor[      0.19699838300000003`, 0.252204821,       0.33320940200000004`]}, {"Directional", RGBColor[      0.15473514000000002`, 0.21284718000000002`,       0.29811516000000005`], ImageScaled[{0, 2, 2}]}, {"Directional",      RGBColor[      0.15473514000000002`, 0.21284718000000002`,       0.29811516000000005`], ImageScaled[{2, 2, 2}]}, {"Directional",      RGBColor[      0.15473514000000002`, 0.21284718000000002`,       0.29811516000000005`], ImageScaled[{2, 0, 2}]}},   AbsoluteThickness[2]],  
Directive[Specularity[GrayLevel[1], 3], RGBColor[   0.560181, 0.691569, 0.194885],   Lighting -> {{"Ambient", RGBColor[      0.1830429875, 0.21424763749999998`,       0.0962851875]}, {"Directional", RGBColor[      0.14004525, 0.17289224999999997`, 0.048721249999999994`],      ImageScaled[{0, 2, 2}]}, {"Directional", RGBColor[      0.14004525, 0.17289224999999997`, 0.048721249999999994`],      ImageScaled[{2, 2, 2}]}, {"Directional", RGBColor[      0.14004525, 0.17289224999999997`, 0.048721249999999994`],      ImageScaled[{2, 0, 2}]}}, AbsoluteThickness[2]],  
Directive[Specularity[GrayLevel[1], 6], RGBColor[   0.922526, 0.385626, 0.209179],   Lighting -> {{"Ambient", RGBColor[      0.30756835, 0.18676585, 0.147065275]}, {"Directional", RGBColor[      0.2306315, 0.0964065, 0.05229475],      ImageScaled[{0, 2, 2}]}, {"Directional", GrayLevel[0.3],      ImageScaled[{2, 2, 2}]}, {"Directional", RGBColor[      0.2306315, 0.0964065, 0.05229475], ImageScaled[{2, 0, 2}]}},   AbsoluteThickness[2]],  
Directive[Specularity[GrayLevel[1], 6], RGBColor[   0.528488, 0.470624, 0.701351],   Lighting -> {{"Ambient", RGBColor[      0.41139519999999996`, 0.3882496, 0.4805404]}, {"Directional",      RGBColor[0.264244, 0.235312, 0.3506755],      ImageScaled[{0, 2, 2}]}, {"Directional", Hue[0.7, 1, 1],      ImageScaled[{2, 2, 2}]}, {"Directional", RGBColor[      0.264244, 0.235312, 0.3506755], ImageScaled[{2, 0, 2}]}},   AbsoluteThickness[2]],  
Directive[Specularity[GrayLevel[1], 6], RGBColor[   0.772079, 0.431554, 0.102387],       Lighting -> {{"Ambient", RGBColor[      0.35441579999999995`, 0.2863108, 0.2204774]}, {"Directional",      RGBColor[0.19301974999999993`, 0.1078885, 0.02559675],      ImageScaled[{0, 2, 2}]}, {"Directional", GrayLevel[0.3],      ImageScaled[{2, 2, 2}]}, {"Directional", RGBColor[      0.19301974999999993`, 0.1078885, 0.02559675],      ImageScaled[{2, 0, 2}]}}, AbsoluteThickness[2]],  
Directive[Specularity[GrayLevel[1], 6], RGBColor[   0.363898, 0.618501, 0.782349],   Lighting -> {{"Ambient", RGBColor[      0.28733552, 0.34844024, 0.38776376]}, {"Directional", RGBColor[      0.10916940000000003`, 0.1855503, 0.2347047],      ImageScaled[{0, 2, 2}]}, {"Directional", RGBColor[      0.10916940000000003`, 0.1855503, 0.2347047],      ImageScaled[{2, 2, 2}]}, {"Directional", RGBColor[      0.10916940000000003`, 0.1855503, 0.2347047],      ImageScaled[{2, 0, 2}]}}, AbsoluteThickness[2]],  
Directive[Specularity[GrayLevel[1], 3], RGBColor[1, 0.75, 0],   Lighting -> {{"Ambient", RGBColor[      0.334, 0.2755000000000001, 0.1]}, {"Directional", RGBColor[      0.26, 0.19500000000000006`, 0.],      ImageScaled[{0, 2, 2}]}, {"Directional", GrayLevel[0.1],      ImageScaled[{2, 2, 2}]}, {"Directional", RGBColor[      0.26, 0.19500000000000006`, 0.], ImageScaled[{2, 0, 2}]}},   AbsoluteThickness[2]],  
Directive[Specularity[GrayLevel[1], 6], RGBColor[   0.647624, 0.37816, 0.614037],   Lighting -> {{"Ambient", RGBColor[      0.40723968, 0.3210112, 0.39649184000000004`]}, {"Directional",      RGBColor[0.2590496, 0.151264, 0.24561480000000002`],      ImageScaled[{0, 2, 2}]}, {"Directional", GrayLevel[0.3],      ImageScaled[{2, 2, 2}]}, {"Directional", RGBColor[      0.2590496, 0.151264, 0.24561480000000002`],      ImageScaled[{2, 0, 2}]}}, AbsoluteThickness[2]],  
Directive[Specularity[GrayLevel[1], 6], RGBColor[   0.571589, 0.586483, 0.],   Lighting -> {{"Ambient", RGBColor[      0.36004492, 0.36421523999999994`, 0.2]}, {"Directional",      RGBColor[0.20005615, 0.20526904999999995`, 0.],      ImageScaled[{0, 2, 2}]}, {"Directional", RGBColor[      0.20005615, 0.20526904999999995`, 0.],      ImageScaled[{2, 2, 2}]}, {"Directional", RGBColor[      0.20005615, 0.20526904999999995`, 0.], ImageScaled[{2, 0, 2}]}},   AbsoluteThickness[2]]
```

[image]