# Different colors when comparing Plot3D V9 and V10

Tags: plotting, color, version-10

I am trying to create Plot3D with same color as we used to get in V9 but without success.
I used `PlotTheme -> "Classic"` in V10 but the results looks like somehow not the same as V9.
I have also copied the FullForm between V9 and V10 and again the plots are different.

does anyone know the reason behind this?

V9:

[image]

V10:

[image]

Comment: `PlotTheme->"Classic"` *should* be setting `Lighting->"Classic"` to get the old lights.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

An alternative to @Rahul's suggested fix:

```
Plot3D[Sin[x+y^2],{x,-3,3},{y,-2,2}, PlotTheme->{"Classic","ClassicLights"}]
```

[image]

The associated `Lighting` setting matches the one in Rahul's post:

```
 "DefaultLighting"/.(Method /.Charting`ResolvePlotTheme["ClassicLights", Plot3D])
 (* {{"Ambient", RGBColor[0.312, 0.188, 0.4]},
     {"Directional", RGBColor[0.8, 0, 0], ImageScaled[{2, 0, 2}]}, 
     {"Directional", RGBColor[0, 0.8, 0], ImageScaled[{2, 2, 2}]}, 
     {"Directional", RGBColor[0, 0, 0.8], ImageScaled[{0, 2, 2}]}} *)
```

Update: Few more combinations of options that give the same result:

```
Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotTheme -> "Classic", Lighting -> "Classic"]
(* thanks: Algohi *)

Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, Lighting -> "Classic", PlotTheme->None]
```

Comment: Ah! This is the better solution!

Comment: @kguler I have got this works also Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotTheme -> "Classic", 
 Lighting -> "Classic"]

Comment: @Algohi, nice find! `Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, Lighting -> "Classic", PlotTheme->None]` also works.

Comment: Since this is the canonical solution, I'll delete my answer and leave this here: [the previous default lighting settings](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27639/484).

Comment: In the Trial version of Mathematica 10 just PlotTheme->"Classic" does very little (it worked well in Prerelease 13). But adding PlotTheme -> {"Classic", "ClassicLights"} does get back to Version 9 (and earlier) coloring. Why would they want to change this anyway??

Answer (score 2):

It quite possible that the default lighting has not changed, but that `PlotTheme -> "Classic"` introduces an explicit color function. That would make a difference because as it says under [`Lighting`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Lighting.html) in the docs:

> Lighting->Automatic uses ambient light together with four light sources fixed relative to the final displayed image. With the typical default setting ColorFunction->Automatic, colored light sources are used; if an explicit setting for ColorFunction is given, the light sources are taken to be white. »

Further, [`PlotTheme`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PlotTheme.html) says that "Classic" is a

> historical design of plots to remain compatible with existing uses

Note "compatible", not "identical".

Comment: Well, if you compare the first three images on the documentation page "[Change the Lighting of Plots](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/ChangeTheLightingOfPlots.html)", which are supposed to look the same (and did in previous versions), it is clear that the default lighting *has* changed.