# Plot3D PlotStyle V10.3 vs V7

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

This is the from the the very good book of Hazrat

[image]

He used Mathematica 7.0.

In Mathematica 10.3 one gets

```
f[x_, y_] := Sin[x^2 + y^2] Exp[-x^2] + Cos[x^2 + y^2]

g2 = Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
  Axes -> False, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

How can I restore the `PlotStyle` of version 7?
Thanks.

Comment: `PlotTheme -> "Classic"`.

Comment: Or `PlotTheme -> None`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I edited the question and I added the figure from the book in order to make "visible" the difference. Initially I forgot it:-)!

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54606/18476

Comment: Thanks. I tend to prefer the `PlotTheme` of version 7. Why did it change?

Comment: Because `PlotTheme` was introduced in version 10.0.

Comment: Ok! Big error. I should have said simply that I prefer the...output of `Plot3d` of version 7:-)!