# The default ColorFunction of DensityPlot before v10?

Tags: plotting, color, implementation-details

The default `ColorFunction` of `Plot`, `Plot3D` before v10 is respectively mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5392857/1551513) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27623/1871), but I failed to find a related post for that of `DensityPlot`.

If I knew this, I could use `ArrayPlot` to imitate `DensityPlot` more perfectly!:

```
Row[{DensityPlot[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, Frame -> None], 
     ArrayPlot[Compile[{}, With[{r = Range[0, 3, 1/40]}, Sin[r #] & /@ r]][], 
               ColorFunction -> "Aquamarine", DataReversed -> True, Frame -> None]}]
```

[image]

Comment: "LakeColors"...

Comment: @BrettChampion Oh……I see. You can make this into an answer, anyway it's not that obvious, I think.

Comment: No, it's not obvious, which is why I gave you a way to find the function without guesswork.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's find out:

```
classicDensityPlot = 
  Trace[
    DensityPlot[x y, {x, y} ∈ Disk[], PlotTheme -> "Classic"],
    _Blend &
  ] // Flatten // First // ReleaseHold

ArrayPlot[Compile[{}, With[{r = Range[0, 3, 1/40]}, Sin[r #] & /@ r]][], 
 ColorFunction -> classicDensityPlot, DataReversed -> True, Frame -> None]
```

[image]

[image]