# What is the default ColorFunction for MatrixPlot?

Tags: plotting, color, implementation-details

I think the the default `ColorFunction` for `ArrayPlot` is `ColorNegate[RGBColor[{#, #, #}]] &` (where `0 <= # <= 1`):

[image]

But I can't figure out the default `ColorFunction` for `MatrixPlot`, so could anyone give me some hint?

PS:

What I want to do is to modify the default `ColorFunction` of `MatrixPlot` a little, so I should find its RGB function first (in my opinion).

Comment: [From the chat room.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2234?m=5959839#5959839)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, this turns out to be version related. Based on the experience from [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/71893/1871):

### In v9.0.1 or earlier

After some trial and error, I obtain:

```
colorFunctionMatrixPlot = 
    Trace[MatrixPlot@{{1}}, _[Blend[__]] &] // Flatten // First // ReleaseHold
```

> ```
> Quiet[Blend[{{0., RGBColor[0.260487, 0.136843, 0.891569]}, {0.166667, 
>      RGBColor[0.230198, 0.499962, 0.848188]}, {0.333333, 
>      RGBColor[0.392401, 0.658762, 0.797589]}, {0.499999, 
>      RGBColor[0.648371, 0.823316, 0.898802]}, {0.5, GrayLevel[1]}, {0.500001, 
>      RGBColor[0.857832, 0.857603, 0.654231]}, {0.666667, 
>      RGBColor[0.913252, 0.790646, 0.462837]}, {0.833333, 
>      RGBColor[0.860243, 0.558831, 0.00695811]}, {1, RGBColor[1., 0.43125, 0.]}}, #1]] &
> ```

```
MatrixPlot[{{1, 2, 1}, {3, 0, 1}, {0, 0, -1}}, ColorFunction -> colorFunctionMatrixPlot]
```

[image]

### In v10

```
colorFunctionMatrixPlot = 
    Trace[MatrixPlot@{{1}}, Blend[__]&] // Flatten // First // ReleaseHold;
colorFunctionMatrixPlot[[1, 1]] = colorFunctionMatrixPlot[[1, 1]];
colorFunctionMatrixPlot
```

> ```
> Blend[{{0., RGBColor[0.260487, 0.356, 0.891569]}, {0.166667, 
>     RGBColor[0.230198, 0.499962, 0.848188]}, {0.333333, 
>     RGBColor[0.392401, 0.658762, 0.797589]}, {0.499999, 
>     RGBColor[0.964837, 0.982332, 0.98988]}, {0.5, RGBColor[1, 1, 1]}, {0.500001, 
>     RGBColor[0.95735, 0.957281, 0.896269]}, {0.666667, 
>     RGBColor[0.913252, 0.790646, 0.462837]}, {0.833333, 
>     RGBColor[0.860243, 0.558831, 0.00695811]}, {1., RGBColor[1., 0.42, 0.]}}, #1] &
> ```

Notice the color scheme has been changed a bit. See the comments below for more details.

Comment: I'm fresh to Mathematica. Could you please give me a example about how to call your `ColorFunction` in `MatrixPlot`?

Comment: When I input your definition for `colorFunctionMatrixPlot`, what I get back is `First::nofirst: {} has zero length and no first element. >>`.  The result of `Trace[MatrixPlot@{{1}}, Quiet[Blend[__]] &]` is simply `{}`

Comment: @JasonB Can this be related to the version? I'm in v9.0.1. What if you try pattern `Blend[__] &` instead?

Comment: Removing the `Quiet` fixed it.  It now returns ``Blend[System`PlotThemeDump`$ThemeDefaultMatrix, #1] &``  (using version 10.3)

Comment: Interestingly, the color scheme changed a little bit, the color for zero in my version is `RGBColor[0.260487, 0.356, 0.891569]` which is a teensy bit lighter than your output above

Answer (score 3):

We can get the default color function for `MatrixPlot` using `` Themes`DefaultStyles ``:

```
dcf = "DefaultColorFunction" /. Themes`DefaultStyles[MatrixPlot][[All, 2]]
```

> ```
>  Blend[System`PlotThemeDump`$ThemeDefaultMatrix, #1] &
> ```

```
System`PlotThemeDump`$ThemeDefaultMatrix
```

[image]

```
MatrixPlot[{{1, 2, 1}, {3, 0, 1}, {0, 0, -1}}, ColorFunction -> dcf]
```

[image]