# How do I find which color gradient is being used with the Automatic parameter?

Tags: plotting, color

How do I find which color scheme is `MatrixPlot` using to color the plot? I need this info because I want to turn the `ColorFunctionScaling` to `False`, but if I do it the automatic `ColorFunction` changes the color gradient:

```
Data1 = Table[Table[RandomReal[0.8], {j, 20}], {i, 20}];
MatrixPlot[Data1, 
  FrameLabel -> {Style["Test", Bold, 14], None, None,Style["Test", Bold, 14]}, 
  ColorFunction -> Automatic, 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> True, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

and with `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`

```
MatrixPlot[Data1,
  FrameLabel -> {Style["Test", Bold, 14], None, None,Style["Test", Bold, 14]}, 
  ColorFunction -> Automatic,
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic,
  ImageSize -> Large]
```

Also, the color legend disappears...

[image]

Comment: This is a bug in `MatrixPlot`, I will report it.  The default theme can be found via ``Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[$PlotTheme, MatrixPlot]``, you see the color function is ``Blend[System`PlotThemeDump`$ThemeDefaultMatrix, #1] &``.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/104039/12