# Correcting the Color Scale of a MatrixPlot

Tags: plotting, matrix, legending

I did a MatrixPlot of a set of values that range between 0 and 1. I got the following first plot with no problems:

[image]

As we can see from the legend, the values range between 0 and 1. Now, I am doing another MatrixPlot with a set of smaller values that range between 0.01 and 0.22. I got this plot:

[image]

I want the second plot to use the same scale used by the first plot (between 0 and 1) and hence the same color scale so we can compare the two plots with each other. How can I tell Mathematica to use the same scale of the first plot for second plot?

Comment: Related: [104989](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104989).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this, we need the default color function used by `MatrixPlot`, which we can get [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104044/731):

```
cf = Blend[{{0., RGBColor[0.260487, 0.356, 0.891569]}, {0.166667, 
      RGBColor[0.230198, 0.499962, 0.848188]}, {0.333333, 
      RGBColor[0.392401, 0.658762, 0.797589]}, {0.499999, 
      RGBColor[0.964837, 0.982332, 0.98988]}, {0.5, 
      RGBColor[1, 1, 1]}, {0.500001, 
      RGBColor[0.95735, 0.957281, 0.896269]}, {0.666667, 
      RGBColor[0.913252, 0.790646, 0.462837]}, {0.833333, 
      RGBColor[0.860243, 0.558831, 0.00695811]}, {1., 
      RGBColor[1., 0.42, 0.]}}, #1] &;
```

Next, we need to rescale it in the same way that `MatrixPlot` rescales it. Namely, so that 0.5 is at 0.

```
cfScaled = cf@Rescale[#, {0, 1}, {0.5, 1}] &;
```

Now we can get the plot like this:

```
MatrixPlot[
 RandomReal[0.2, {10, 10}],
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{Automatic, {0, 1}}],
 ColorFunction -> cfScaled,
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False
 ]
```

[image: Output]

Comments:

- `ColorFunctionScaling` is turned off because otherwise your values, which are approximately between 0 and 0.2, would be rescaled to lie between 0 and 1 before being passed to the color function.
- `cfScaled` has to be an anonymous function, otherwise it won't work because `BarLegend` does not work with named functions. Optionally, one can also use a color scheme from `ColorData` such as `ColorFunction -> ColorData["AvocadoColors"]`.

Answer (score 6):

**Note:** as others have mentioned here already, the option I show here is the simplest correction that works only when your values lie in the {0,1} interval.

When plotting a MatrixPlot, you can set the option [ColorFunctionScaling](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunctionScaling.html) to `False`, because by default the colors will be rescaled between 0 and 1.

Suppose you have two matrices, one with values ranging in the {0,1} interval, and the other in the {0,0.22} interval. Choosing some particular color scheme, in this example the `"TemperatureMap"`, you can plot both of these matrices without rescaling like this:

```
nPts = 100;
myMat1 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {nPts, nPts}];
myMat2 = RandomReal[{0, 0.22}, {nPts, nPts}];

{MatrixPlot[myMat1, ColorFunction -> ColorData["TemperatureMap"], 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, ColorFunctionScaling -> False],
 MatrixPlot[myMat2, ColorFunction -> ColorData["TemperatureMap"], 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, ColorFunctionScaling -> False]}
```

[image]

If this option is not set, the colors will be rescaled:

```
{MatrixPlot[myMat1, ColorFunction -> ColorData["TemperatureMap"], 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic], 
 MatrixPlot[myMat2, ColorFunction -> ColorData["TemperatureMap"], 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic]}
```

[image]

Comment: But how can I use the same colors of the 'First Plot' instead of TemperatureMap colors?

Comment: You can either replace `"TemperatureMap"` for whatever color scheme you like (that is similar to the `'FirstPlot'`), or if you want the exact same color then you need to follow the steps given by @C.E. below, because you'd have to find the particular RGB values that are used in the default `MatrixPlot` function.

Answer (score 6):

You may use the [`ColorFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html), [`ColorFunctionScaling`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunctionScaling.html), and [`PlotLegends`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLegends.html) options of [`MatrixPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixPlot.html).

With

```
SeedRandom[123]
dat1 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 10}];
dat2 = RandomReal[{0.01, 0.22}, {10, 10}];
```

Then

```
MatrixPlot[#,
    ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"BrownCyanTones", {0, 1}}],
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
    PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{Automatic, {0, 1}}]
    ] & /@ {dat1, dat2} // GraphicsRow
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

- The `ColourFunction` specification forces the color gradient to span the provided range.
- The `ColorFunctionScaling` specification prevents the scaling of the values to run between 0 and 1 for the color function.  This is needed for when your data does not span 0 to 1; see additional example below.
- The `PlotLedgends` specification forces the legend to span the specified range; else it will only span the range of the data but will have the correct colours; see additional example below.

So lets take a range of 50 to 100 and not scale the range of the legend do demonstrate the points made above

With

```
SeedRandom[456]
dat3 = RandomReal[{50, 100}, {10, 10}];
dat4 = RandomReal[{55, 65}, {10, 10}];
```

Then

```
MatrixPlot[#,
    ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"BrownCyanTones", {50, 100}}],
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
    PlotLegends -> Automatic
    ] & /@ {dat3, dat4} // GraphicsRow
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice in the plot of `dat4` that the correct colours are used but the legend does not span 50 to 100.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

This is unfortunately a rather hard problem. For values that lie between 0 and 1 the following works:

```
fixedRangeMatrixPlot[data_] := With[{cf = "TemperatureMap", ticks = 8},
  Legended[
   MatrixPlot[data, ColorFunction -> (ColorData[cf][# + 1/2] &), 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False], Placed[
    BarLegend[
     {Function[Blend[cf, #]], {1/2, 1}},
     Rule[Ticks, 
      Table[{.5 (1 + i/(ticks - 1)), N[#, 1] &@(i/(ticks - 1))}, {i, 
        0, ticks - 1}]]
     ], After, Identity]]
  ]
```

Then you can try

```
fixedRangeMatrixPlot@RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 10}]
```

[image: MatrixPlot with "full" range]

```
fixedRangeMatrixPlot@RandomReal[{0, .2}, {10, 10}]
```

[image: MatrixPlot with "partial" range]

I found this "solution" by looking at the output of `FullForm`.