# How to extract the color of the bar-stacked used in BulletGauge?

Tags: graphics, color

How can I extract the colors used by default in the BulletGauge?

[image]

Comment: You mean you want to know which colours are used in the bar, the darkred,blue,greenish etc.?

Comment: @Feyre For a rude use I would use a pick up color of paint-design colors. What I want is the list of colors, as colors as mathematica knows it, or as you describe for a future swaping

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Trace

A programmatic approach using [`Trace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trace.html):

```
Trace[
  BulletGauge[{1, 1.8, 3, 3.4, 4, 5}, {2.4, 2.9}, {0, 3.5, 4.8}],
  _ColorData
] // Flatten // First
```

> ```
> ColorData[63, 1]
> ```

Check:

```
ColorData[63, "ColorList"]
```

[image]

Related examples:

- [The default ColorFunction of DensityPlot before v10?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/71891/121)
- [Extracting unknown ColorFunction from Plot, Plot3D etc](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/112945/extracting-unknown-colorfunction-from-plot-plot3d-etc/123155#123155)

---

#### Spelunking

This can also be found by spelunking the definition of `BulletGauge` itself using tools from:

- [What is the most convenient way to read definitions of in-memory symbols when we don't have the source files? (Spelunking tools)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1742/121)

One find that the inner definition is `` Charting`iLinearGauge ``

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

PrintDefinitions @ Charting`iLinearGauge
```

Within that one finds a hard-coded color source:

```
Charting`padList[{{ColorData[63][#1] &, None}}, numvals]
```

Comment: @mr-wizard Yes, that´s the answer!

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I did:

All Mathematica plotting functions use a range of `ColorData[]`.

```
Table[ColorData[i, "ColorList"], {i, 1, 96}] // TableForm
```

Prints all the `ColorData` lists.
From this you can count (you can change the range of the `Table[]`), that the one you want is `nr63`.

```
ColorData[63, "ColorList"]
```

Gives this list.

```
colours = ColorData[63, "ColorList"]
a = colours[[5]]
colours[[5]] = colours[[6]];
colours[[6]] = a
BulletGauge[{1, 1.8, 3, 3.4, 4, 5}, {2.4, 2.9}, {0, 3.5, 4.8}, 
 ImageSize -> Large, GaugeStyle -> colours]
```

[image]

Comment: ok, I like it,... but... How can I know that BulletGauges use the secuence number 63?

Comment: @MikaIke I updated the answer on your other question.

Comment: @MikaIke Which has now been rolled back, so I edited my answer here.