# Is possible to extract the gray levels used in BulletGauge?

Tags: graphics, color

**THE SOLUTION IS IN THE FIRST COMMENT. I´m waiting for C.E. put as an answer to give the OK.**

Related to  [enter link description here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/124025/how-to-extract-the-color-of-the-bar-stacked-used-in-bulletgauge) where a solution to extract the colors used by BulletGauge was given, using

```
Trace[BulletGauge[{1, 1.8, 3, 3.4, 4, 5}, {2.4, 2.9}, {0,1.56, 3.5, 
4.8}], _ColorData] // Flatten // First
```

How to extract the gray levels used? for example in 
    BulletGauge[{1, 1.8, 3, 3.4, 4, 5}, {2.4, 2.9}, {0, 1.56, 3.5, 4.8}, 
 ImageSize -> Large]

where {0, 1.56, 3.5, 4.8} points indicate the number os levels.

I have tried deleting "First" but no succes.

Comment: `Cases[bg, _GrayLevel, Infinity]` where bg is your `BulletGauge` command, maybe, if it's what you want.

Comment: @C.E. YES, fantastic!! That´s a simple and excelent solution! Please, could you post as an answeer to give the OK ? . Moreover, a "relative" adaptation is a good and "alternative close to solution solution" to the mentioned question: using: 
Cases[bg, _RGBColor, Infinity]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
Cases[bg, _GrayLevel, Infinity]
```

where `bg` is a `BulletGauge`.