# What is the default Lighting in 3D graphics?

Tags: graphics3d

The default value of [`Lighting`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Lighting.html) in 3D graphics typically uses `"Standard"`, with several coloured lights, or `"Neutral"`, depending on the type of plot.

What is the explicit lighting specification for `"Standard"` and `"Neutral"`, in terms of actual light positions, directions, colours and types?

Comment: How about the second answer here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27616/what-is-the-default-colorfunction-for-3d-plots

Comment: @Feyre Yes, that's the answer.  Thank you. I would rather you post it as an answer here because that question seems to ask something different (by the title) and I really couldn't find the answer after searching both here and the documentation ...

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't find an answer in the docs. I searched on "lighting default" and found the answer in the third hit.

Comment: For your perusal: ``System`PlotThemeDump`resolvePlotTheme["DefaultLights", Graphics3D]`` and ``System`PlotThemeDump`resolvePlotTheme["ClassicLights", Graphics3D]``.

Comment: @m_goldberg Well, I didn't search for those specific words as I was concentrating on figuring out what `"Standard"` is.  Of course that seems silly now that I chose those words for the title of the post ... Also, the relevant page doesn't contain the word `"Standard"`.

Comment: @Szabolcs Would you be opposed to closing this question as a duplicate of [(27616)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27616/121) and maybe co-duplicate of [(54606)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54606/121)?  As usual this question would remain as a guidepost for future searches.  It seems to me that although the OP didn't really know how to ask the question he was ultimately asking the same question as you are.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Okay, go ahead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer can be found here: [Change The Lighting Of Plots](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/ChangeTheLightingOfPlots.html) in the official How Tos.

For `"Standard"`/`Automatic`:

```
Graphics3D[Sphere[], 
           Lighting -> {{"Ambient", RGBColor[0.4, 0.2, 0.2]},
                        {"Directional", RGBColor[0, 0.18, 0.5], ImageScaled[{2, 0, 2}]},
                        {"Directional", RGBColor[0.18, 0.5, 0.18], ImageScaled[{2, 2, 3}]},
                        {"Directional", RGBColor[0.5, 0.18, 0], ImageScaled[{0, 2, 2}]},
                        {"Directional", RGBColor[0, 0, 0.18], ImageScaled[{0, 0, 2}]}}]
```

For `"Classic"`:

```
Graphics3D[Sphere[], 
           Lighting -> {{"Ambient", RGBColor[0.312, 0.188, 0.4]},
                        {"Directional", RGBColor[0.8, 0., 0.], ImageScaled[{2, 0, 2}]},
                        {"Directional", RGBColor[0., 0.8, 0.], ImageScaled[{2, 2, 2}]},
                        {"Directional", RGBColor[0., 0., 0.8], ImageScaled[{0, 2, 2}]}}]
```

For `"Neutral"`:

```
Graphics3D[Sphere[], 
           Lighting -> {{"Ambient", RGBColor[0.35, 0.35, 0.35]},
                        {"Directional", RGBColor[0.37, 0.37, 0.37], ImageScaled[{2, 0, 2}]},
                        {"Directional", RGBColor[0.37, 0.37, 0.37], ImageScaled[{2, 2, 2}]},
                        {"Directional", RGBColor[0.37, 0.37, 0.37], ImageScaled[{0, 2, 2}]}}]
```

Comment: I added the one for Neutral too, hope you don't mind :-)  Thanks!  Also, I just learned about ImageScaled.

Comment: No, I should have immediately added it, you did ask about both.