# Extracting tube style from KnotData

Tags: graphics3d, curated-data, knots

How do I extract the tube style (including lighting, viewpoint, ...) from `KnotData["Trefoil"]`

[image: trefoil knot]

and apply it to a space curve, such as

`ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[θ], Sin[θ], Cos[2 θ]}, {θ, 0, 2 π}]`  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Options@KnotData["Trefoil"]
(* {Boxed -> False, PlotRange -> {All, All, All}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {Automatic, Automatic, Automatic}, 
 ViewPoint -> {0, 0.01, 5}} *)
```

You can see the `ViewPoint` above. Since the lighting is not mentioned, it has the [default value](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119804/12).

Generally, for any `Graphics3D`, just paste it in the middle of an `Options[...]` or `Options[..., ViewPoint]`.

Answer (score 4):

```
thickness = 0.1;
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[\[Theta]], Sin[\[Theta]], 
   Cos[2 \[Theta]]}, {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi]},
  PlotPoints -> 360,
  PlotStyle -> White,
  PlotRangePadding -> 2 thickness] /. Line[x__] :> Tube[x, thickness]
```

[image]

The tubes are white, actually. The colors result from the defaults for the graphics option `Lighting`.

Comment: Great.  But HOW did you extract the data?  Just guess and check?

Comment: `Graphics3D` objects can be inspected. The one created by `KnotData["Trefoil"]` just contains a `GraphicsComplex` and the standard color for a `GraphicsComplex` is `White`. That's about the color. `ParametricPlot3D` creates `Graphics3D` objects containing `Line` primitives (if you plot curves) and these can be changed into `Tube` primitives just as above. The `thickness` was a pure guess.

Comment: Note that `PlotStyle -> {White, Tube[thickness]}` may be used instead of post-processing the `Line` objects.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Good to know! And it is rendered with `VertexNormals`! However, do you also see that the ends of the curve are visible this way?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I mean: Can something to be done about that? I wrote my own tubification function long time ago, but it would be nice to know if there is a built-in alternative.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Yes, I can see it. Perhaps due to the open sampling `ParametricPlot` uses. It used not to do that, presumably because one often uses periodic parametrizations. The basic rationale is to let you plot, say, `Log[x]` over `{x, 0 ,1}`, without worrying about singularities at end points. An option to override the sampling method would be nice, but I do not know of one.